# Why is this error coming "Adding comment -- redirecting to wrong page"?

Tags: python, django

this is my views.py file

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    form_class = CommentForm
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    post = self.get_object()
    request = self.request
    is_liked=False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked=True
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'total_likes': post.total_likes(), 'is_liked': is_liked})
    context['form']=CommentForm()
    context ['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()
    return context


class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['cont']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.post = Post
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

this is post_detail.html

```
`
`
`  <form method="post">
      {%csrf_token%}
      {{form|crispy}}
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" value="submit">
    </form>
    <div class="main-comment-section">
      {{comments.count}} Comment {{comments|pluralize}}
      {%for comment in comments%}
        <blockquote class="blockquote">
          <p class="mb-0">{{comment.cont}}</p>
          <footer class="blockquote-footer">by- <cite title="Source Title">{{comment.user | capfirst}}</cite></footer>
        </blockquote>
      {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

` this is my url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ----
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('like/',views.like_post,name="like_post"),
    path('comment/',CommentCreateView.as_view(),name='comment-create'),
    ---
]
```

this is my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content     = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author      = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes       = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='likes',blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def total_likes(self):
    return self.likes.count()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cont = models.TextField()
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __str__(self):
    return '{}-{}'.format(self.post.title,str(self.user.username))
```

when i am submitting form it showing an error of page not found
traceback error:"GET /post/7/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6831
                 Method Not Allowed (POST): /post/7/

this is not like other django error.
it is a http error 405, the error is :This page isn’t workingIf the problem
                                    continues, contat the site owner.
                                    HTTP ERROR 405

Comment: I think you need to add the actiion attribute in your for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#building-a-form

Comment: Your url in urls has `name='post-detail'`, however, your success url is `return reverse('post_detail',[...]`. Underscore vs. hyphen.